# Retrieved time not converted to current time zone

Tags: android

I have to convert the time which i get as input and convert to current time zone which had been set in device and display.
I tried some extent but the time not changed while converting.Have posted my code..

```
String dateandtime="3/14/2013 2:38am" //EDT time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone z = cal.getTimeZone();
SimpleDateFormat  format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma");  
format1.setTimeZone(z);
cal.setTime(format1.parse(dateandtime));
```

The value of "dateandtime" wil be EDT timezone and should convert to any of current time zone.. I receive the same date and time as output..

Comment: Did you check the current timezone and the timezone you are setting, are they different?

Comment: yes,i have checked they are different only

Comment: http://niravranpara.blogspot.com/

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara:where can i find time conversion in your blog?

Comment: Your calendar and date formatter are using the same time zone which, because you have not set it, will be the system time zone.  The string you are using does not contain time zone information (you have commented it's EDT but your code does not know that).  You should set the calendar time zone to the tz you want to convert from and the date formatter tz to the zone you want to convert to.